# Express.js res.render dot name file

Tags: node.js, express

How can I use dot named file on `res.render()` in express.js?
For instance,

There is template file named `view.sample.ejs` , I want to render it

```
app.get('/sample', function(req, res){
    res.render('view.sample');
})
```

The result is,

```
Error: Cannot find module 'sample'
```

How can I use dots?

(plus)

I want to name follow mvc model, like

```
sample.model.js
sample.controller.js
sample.view.ejs
sample.view.update.ejs ...
```

No problem js file, but render ejs file I couldn't.

Comment: Is it looking for 'sample' in 'view/sample.ejs' rather than a file named 'view.sample.ejs'?

Comment: @Michael No, no directory. just view.sample.ejs :)

Comment: To include other periods in the name, you'll have to provide the full file name in the argument – `res.render('view.sample.ejs');`. Express is assuming `.sample` is the file extension by its presence in the argument, so it won't add `.ejs` to find the file you want. (Otherwise, you'll have to consider using different punctuation.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we look at the library `node_modules/express/lib/view.js`, we find that the design of the path to the template everything after the dot in the file name shall be considered as an extension:

```
this.ext = extname(name); // 'view.sample' => '.sample'
this.name = name;         // 'view.sample' => 'view.sample'
```

And when we try to load the corresponding file extension engine will generate an error:

```
if (!opts.engines[this.ext]) { // '.sample' engine not found
  // try load engine and throw error
  opts.engines[this.ext] = require(this.ext.substr(1)).__express;
}
```

Ok, what to do? Just add the extension:

```
app.get('/sample', function(req, res){
  res.render('view.sample.ejs');
})
```